# Variations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a problem with solving this. How many 7 digit numbers can be formed with digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 if the digit 2 appears in each number at least twice. I thought of using variations with repetitions but i am not sure how to use it properly since i have the minimum number of repetition of a selected digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the total number of 7-digit numbers and subtract the quantities:

$\ \ \ A=$the number of 7-digit numbers with no twos

and

$\ \ \ B=$the number of 7-digit numbers with exactly one two.

Answer (score 2):

- How many 7-digit numbers (with no 9 or 0 digits) are there with precisely two 2s?
- How many 7-digit numbers (with no 9 or 0 digits) are there with precisely three 2s?
- How many 7-digit numbers (with no 9 or 0 digits) are there with precisely four 2s?
- ......
- How many 7-digit numbers (with no 9 or 0 digits) are there with precisely seven 2s?

Comment: oh I'm stupid ..Thanks xD

Comment: @anon what if the repetition is global meaning not specific to a digit but whole number? How to get all the variations with n repetitions?

Comment: @Eftekhari Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @anon Thanks for the reply. Solved the problem, you could find it in my latest questions on stackoverflow.com